# css animation fades in, but won't fade out

Tags: css, css-animations

This is a simplified version of something I'm trying to implement. When a `label` is clicked, it toggles a checkbox and causes an overlay to appear using `display:block` and fade in. In the overlay is another `label` which is supposed to do the same thing in reverse. However, the overlay doesn't fade out, but vanishes abruptly.

I've been fiddling with `normal/reverse` and `forwards/backwards` but nothing changes. I know this is just some detail of how CSS animations work, but it's just not clear to me how to reverse the animation when the `#toggle` is unchecked.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5cnsn38L/

```css
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    1% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    animation: fadein ease-in 0.6s 1 reverse forwards;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .overlay {
    animation: fadein ease-in 0.6s 1 normal forwards;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="overlay"> 
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <label for="toggle">Click to deactivate</label>
</div> 
<label for="toggle">Click to activate</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with using `display: none` and `display: block`. Why don't you use `transition` and `opacity` instead? It is much simpler

```css
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity ease-in 0.6s;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="overlay"> 
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <label for="toggle">Click to deactivate</label>
</div> 
<label for="toggle">Click to activate</label>
```

Comment: Because zero opacity elements still block users from clicking the elements beneath them.

Comment: @Blazemonger - Use pointer-events: none; to let clicks pass through elements on top of others.